# Looking for a battle map designer with ice-themed objects

Tags: pathfinder-1e, tools, tool-recommendation, map-making

I am looking for an online map designer I can use to make a battle map for Pathfinder. The theme is supposed to be icy and harsh. I already tried [Dungeon Painter Online](http://pyromancers.com), and I found in terms of features it is almost perfect for what I am trying to do, except for a lack of ice/snow-themed objects.

Is there a similar battle map designer, but with more icy looking objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maptool](http://www.rptools.net/index.php?page=maptool) is a viable (local and regional) map editor.

It is even capable of hosting live games online.

I can't check at the moment, but there may not be snow textures already installed. Luckily, there is a sizable fanbase of texture artists. You may be able to find what you need in the case that snow textures aren't included on the official rptools forums, e.g. [these textures](http://forums.rptools.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=4104).

Answer (score 1):

If you have time to work with raw textures in a generic mapping tool, take a look at [Genetica](http://www.spiralgraphics.biz/genetica.htm). There is [a free download "viewer" application](http://www.spiralgraphics.biz/viewer/index.htm), and it has [some pretty ice and snow presets](http://www.spiralgraphics.biz/packs/snow_ice/index.htm).

The licensing of graphics rendered from the presets is [free for personal use](http://www.spiralgraphics.biz/packs/usage_rights.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a "cartogropher" or dungeon designer?

For cartography - Autorealm is a safe bet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoREALM

For dungeon mapping then unless you're willing to pay, they're all very basic and snowless!

Comment: this looks like nothing more than a new paint tool. I am looking for a dungeon creator with pre made objects for walls and buildings and so forth...

Comment: hence why I asked whether you were looking for a cartogrophy style program or dungeon designer! and as above, unless you're willing to pay for the software, or buy an object/set pack then the free ones don't meet your requirements

Comment: Dungeon / battle map mapping, based on the link provided.